# How to prevent GCE enforcer from deleting firewall rules?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've had instances on GCE hosting multiple websites for years. Suddenly, without any warning or notice, my instances went unreachable on 6/19.

After wasting several hours trying to debug this, I found that a `gceenforcer@system.gserviceaccount.com` service account was deleting firewall rules from my account! Even if I click "Enable HTTP/HTTPS traffic" when configuring the instance, a few minutes later the GCE enforcer deletes the rules again.

So many questions (and so frustrating!). What is GCE enforcer? Why is it deleting my firewall rules without permission or notice? How do I disable it?

Comment: To add more color, the GCE enforcer seems specifically to be deleting the `default-allow-ssh`, `default-allow-http` and `default-allow-https` rules. I can't find any documentation on it, nor any useful pointers online.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a Googler, or were you part of Google in the past?

It seems that this is an account that enforces firewall rules on projects that were created when you were a Google employee.

Comment: Never worked at Google, so not sure why this is happening. What sucks is the lack of transparency and visibility. To get any technical support, Google forces me to pay. Until then, my instances are hosed -- this feels like extortion!